# get-localuser Passwordexpires in seconds (left from now)

Tags: powershell

```
get-localuser |fl brings back the Date in that format: 

PasswordExpires        : 10/01/2022 15:31:34
```

how can i get this date counted in seconds from now? with powershell?
can someone help me out?

```
AccountExpires         : 
Description            : 
Enabled                : True
FullName               : test-deleteme
PasswordChangeableDate : 29/11/2021 15:31:34
PasswordExpires        : 10/01/2022 15:31:34
UserMayChangePassword  : True
PasswordRequired       : True
PasswordLastSet        : 29/11/2021 15:31:34
LastLogon              : 
Name                   : test-deleteme
PrincipalSource        : Local
ObjectClass            : User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `PasswordExpired` value does not in itself have a specific format - but PowerShell chooses a default format based on your locale once it need to output it to the screen.

If you want to calculate the duration from now until the date specified in `PasswordExpiration`, use the subtraction operator (`-`) inside a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties):

```
Get-LocalUser |Select-Object Name,@{Name='PasswordExpiresInSeconds'; Expression={$_.PasswordExpires - (Get-Date)}}
```

This will produce a `[timespan]` value describing the duration. To get just the number of seconds, reference the `TotalSeconds` property on the resulting timespan object:

```
Get-LocalUser |Select-Object Name,@{Name='PasswordExpiresInSeconds'; Expression={$($_.PasswordExpires - (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds -as [int]}}
```